# WxPython - Clear event queue and pending tasks

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm working on a project where `wxPython` (3.0.2.0) is used, however some unit-tests are failing from time to time because wx tries to update the GUI just after it is closed.

In the function that closes everything, a `wx.SafeYield(onlyIfNeeded=True)` is placed first to ensure the event queue is empty. Then some threads are killed and the following loop is being ran:

```
for item in wx.GetTopLevelWindows():
    if item != self:
        if isinstance(item, wx.Dialog):
            if item.IsModal():
                item.EndModal(wx.ID_CANCEL)
            else:
                item.Destroy()
        else:
            item.Close()
self.Destroy()
```

However, after this loop, apparently a delayed wx call (probably called with [wx.CallLater](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.CallLater-class.html)) still tries to update a GUI element resulting in a `<class 'wx._core.PyDeadObjectError'> PyDeadObjectError('The C++ part of the ArtworkPanel object has been deleted, attribute access no longer allowed.',)` crash.

Is there a way to clear this CallLater queue? I took a look at [stopping the entire EventLoop](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_event_loop_base.html#a33c979a2f81d59cc340096a8a1dd49a5) and maybe restart it, but I am not even sure if that works and if there exists a better way to do this, maybe using [DeletePendingEvents](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#a6e7f9cf4ebd0623c1d94979855d096f8)?

**Is there a way to cancel all pending tasks in wx so that when you exit your application, no (delayed) functions will crash the application?**

Comment: Can you modify the function passed to `CallLater`?  Could it be made aware that it sometimes runs after object destruction and handle that situation appropriately?

Comment: @g.d.d.c unfortunately there are already checks in place. The function is in a panel object where it is being checked if self and self.list (the panel contains a list) are not none. The python objects seem to still exist while the C++ part is deleted. Wrapping it in a try except works, but is by no means a fix for this problem and will eventually show itself in another (wx) object.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I don't have much information and this is completely untested, but as you suggested, `DeletePendingEvents` seem to do the trick.  On your loop where you force dialogs/windows to end/be destroyed, you might call `item.DeletePendingEvents()`.  The documentation seems to be somewhat optimistic, but would a `callLater` be subscribed as a queue event?  I cannot tell for sure.